# Sum colum in an html table using C# and html-agility-pack

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

How do I sum the values in a specific column of a specific table when the number of rows are unpredictable? Note that the header row contains text and uses "" instead of "".

Using the sample html below I would want to sum the values from the fourth column of the first table and ignore all other tables.

I assume the first step is to get the count of the rows in the first table, and the next step is to construct a calculation that performs a sum ignoring the first row.

Example HTML;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td>City</td>
    <td>Number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Scott</td>
    <td>555-2345</td>
    <td>Chicago</td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill</td>
    <td>555-1243</td>
    <td>Detroit</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ted</td>
    <td>555-3567</td>
    <td>Columbus</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Year</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Abraham</td>
    <td>1865</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Martin</td>
    <td>1968</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>1963</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here reference code that I used for other purposes - (to get table count).

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String html = "C:/TestFile.html";

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(html);

        int count = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").Count;

        // output to Console
        Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!

One more thing...
Are there some resources you might suggest to help me understand the syntax so that I might gain a bit of independence. (I am a newbie to HTML-Agility Pack and I worked a little with C# years ago)

I have the CHM file for HAP 1.4.6 and I have tried to navigate HtmlAgilityPack in Visual Studio's object browser, but I don't understanding what I'm see there. Please direct me to some resources that could help get me started. I would be greatly appreciate having a bit more of a clue to what I am trying to do.

Thanks too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the sum of last column(skipping the first row) of first table.

```
 var sum = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
              .Elements("tr")
              .Skip(1)
              .Sum(tr => int.Parse(tr.Elements("td").Last().InnerText));
```

This returns **74**

Comment: Thanks! But I would like to understand how it works so that I can get the sum of a specific column that may not be the last one or from a table that may not be the first one. (What I supplied was a sample.) Would you suggest some resources that can help me with this. Please see the last two paragraphs of my original Message.