# Syntax questions C# Html-Agility-Pack

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

This code sums the ***last column*** in the first table contained in an html document. (It ignores the first row.)

1.) How do I sum a ***specified column*** rather than just the last one?

```
var sum = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
          .Elements("tr")
          .Skip(1)
          .Sum(tr => int.Parse(tr.Elements("td").Last().InnerText));
```

Where this code came from...
I was given this code in reply to: ([Sum colum in an html table using C# and html-agility-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406331/sum-colum-in-an-html-table-using-c-sharp-and-html-agility-pack)) 
but I could not get any explanation of how it worked.

What I have done to try to answer my question...
I have worked for many hours trying to understand the syntax. My efforts have included; VS Object Browser, Html-Agility-Pack CHM documentation, W3Schools Tutorial on XPath and  experimentation with the code. I am still a bit lost. I want to better understand the syntax so that I can continue with my project with a degree of independence.

2.) **Below is my best interpretations of the syntax. Where am I wrong? Where am I missing something?**

```
var sum = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
```

The above gets the first table. If it were `//table[2]` it would get the 2nd table

```
.Elements("tr")
```

Does the above specify that the sum is going to be over row-set?

```
.Skip(1)
```

The first row is excluded from the row-set (column) to be summed.

```
.Sum(tr => int.Parse(tr.Elements("td").Last().InnerText));
```

The above is a bit puzzling, but I will try...

```
.Sum(
```

Sum statement started

```
tr =>
```

What is "tr"? It is not in quotes as it appears withing parents. It is not a key word is it? Explain.
The fragment above begins the range of the rows (column) that will be summed.

```
int.Parse(
```

converts text to integers

```
tr.Elements("td").Last().InnerText));
```

Confusing???

```
tr
```

Her is that "tr" again

```
tr.Element(
```

From VS Object Browser `.Elements()` "Gets all first generation elements in collection". What does that mean?

```
tr.Elements("td")
```

"td" specifies that it is the data elements that are being summed

```
tr.Elements("td").Last()
```

The `.Last()` specifies that the range over which the "td" is summed is to occur on the last column. 
Would I be right that there are alternative ways to write this? 
How does one specify anything other than the "last" column? How would one specify the 3rd column?

```
.InnerText
```

Why is `.InnerText` necessary? Doesn't `int.Parse()` take its contents as a string and convert it to int? What am I missing?

3.) **Can you recommend any learning resources for html-agility-pack?** I have just taken the W3Schools tutorial for XPath. I see remote syntax similarity but nothing that appears to be very helpful for working with tables.

Sample html that the code above can run against:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Product Group A</th>
    <th>Mat'l</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
    <th>Size</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ELL</td>
    <td>Plastic1</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEE</td>
    <td>Plastic2</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Straight</td>
    <td>Plastic3</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>71</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Product Group B</th>
    <th>Mat'l</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
    <th>Size</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Plumb Bob</td>
    <td>Bronze1</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hammer</td>
    <td>Bronze2</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sleeve Bearing</td>
    <td>Bronze3</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hopefully someone will chime in with a more complete answer explaining the syntax, but for now, you can sum column n by changing .Last() to .ElementAt(n)

Comment: The code mixes XPATH syntax (//table) and LINQ syntax with lambda expression (the 'tr' thing). You don't have to learn LINQ and lambda to use HTML Agility Pack, you can use XPATH plus regular c# code, but many people like it that's why it's supported. More on Lambda here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx  PS: you should ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Simon, thanks. Your replies are very helpful.

Comment: dlev, thanks for the code!